# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' when using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm working with the boot camp 100 Days of code of UDEMY. Currently I am working on the webscraping lesson using BeautifulSoup, however, I have not been able to complete the classes because I am geting a type error that I do not know why is happening and how to solve as the code is very simple. Here, my phyton code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("website.html") as file:
    html_doc = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title.name)
```

Here the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xarss\Desktop\100 days of python\Webdev_projects\Websrapingproyect\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    html_doc = file.read()
  File "C:\Users\xarss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 281: character maps to <undefined>
```

I already try to re-install beautiful soup package and I am still having the same problem and try using other html files and the problem presist.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angela's Personal Site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="name">Angela Yu</h1>
    <p><em>Founder of <strong><a href="https://www.appbrewery.co/">The App Brewery</a></strong>.</em></p>
    <p>I am an iOS and Web Developer. I ❤️ coffee and motorcycles.</p>
    <hr>
    <h3 class="heading">Books and Teaching</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>The Complete iOS App Development Bootcamp</li>
        <li>The Complete Web Development Bootcamp</li>
        <li>100 Days of Code - The Complete Python Bootcamp</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <h3 class="heading">Other Pages</h3>
    <a href="https://angelabauer.github.io/cv/hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
    <a href="https://angelabauer.github.io/cv/contact-me.html">Contact Me</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are missing an indentation for the `with` block

Comment: Yes, that was an error when posting the question, but in my original code is indented. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common error which we get while opening a file if we don't know the encoding.

One of the below methods may work.

```
with open("website.html", errors="ignore") as file:

with open("website.html", errors='replace') as file:

with open("website.html", 'rb') as file:
```

Comment: Cannot vote yet, but the all these answers worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from the encoding of the file not being `cp1252` (which is used by default when using `open`).

You will have to figure out which encoding is used then specify it when opening the file.

In this case, as you can see on line 5, the file is encoded in utf-8 :

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Here is the updated code :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("website.html", encoding="utf-8") as file:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.title.string)
```

Hope this helps, don't forget to accept an answer if your issue is solved.

Comment: Thanks, I already corrected the errors and also try your solution, and now I am getting other errors, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @XareniGalindo, so i can try to reproduce the error, could you link to the webpage you downloaded as an html file ?

Comment: I added the html code into my question as is very short

Comment: @XareniGalindo, I adapted my answer. it was an encoding issue